# What's the usage of HashedWheelTimer in Netty?

Tags: java, timer, netty

I'm learning Netty these days and came to the class `HashedWheelTimer`.

I read the source code and already know how it is working. But I cannot find its usage in the source code.

What I want to know is:

1. Does Netty use HashedWheelTimer in its own code, or just provide it for convenience?
2. If it's for convenience, what's the usage scenario?

Answer (score 1):

The javadocs states:

> [`HashedWheelTimer` is] a `Timer` optimized for approximated I/O timeout scheduling.

So one usage / use-case is *doing* approximated I/O timeout scheduling.

> Does Netty use HashedWheelTimer in its own code

Yes.  Refer to the GrepCode [usage](http://grepcode.com/search/usages?type=type&id=repository.jboss.org%24nexus%24content%24repositories%24releases@org.jboss.netty%24netty@3.2.0.CR1@org%24jboss%24netty%24util@HashedWheelTimer&k=u) cross-reference for the class.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Actually I'm using Netty 4.1. Using grepcode.com to search HashedWheelTimer  usage in Netty 4.1, I only find Logger/Member variables/Inner class was using it. Here is the [link](http://grepcode.com/search/usages?id=repo1.maven.org$maven2@io.netty$netty-common@4.1.0.Beta5@io$netty$util@HashedWheelTimer&start=0&type=type&k=u)

Comment: Netty 3.X used it a lot in handler, for example ReadTimeOutHandler. Netty 4.1 seems not used it much but used JDK Priority Queue and Executors. I think Netty Community should clean the doc and make it clearer.

Comment: @JianJin - I suggest that you join the community and help them.  At any rate, complaining about it here (in StackOverflow) is pointless.

Comment: agree, i am always helping the community. review the code, review the book. Just want more people to join in. This is not complaint, just suggestion.

Comment: @JianJin - Well 1) it sounds like a complaint, 2) suggesting it here is pointless for the same reason that complaining here is pointless, and 3) don't suggest that "the community" does it when you can do it yourself (as a member of the community).